# Limit with arbitrary function

Tags: limits

Does anyone know how to solve this limit?

$\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x-h)}\right)^\frac{1}{h}-1}{h} $

where $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous at $x$?

Comment: I guess we can assume it is.

Comment: We also need to assume that $f(x) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming continuity
$$f(x-h)=f(x)-h f'(x)+O\left(h^2\right)$$
$$\frac{f(x)}{f(x-h)}=1+\frac{h f'(x)}{f(x)}+O\left(h^2\right)$$
$$\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x-h)} \right)=\frac{h f'(x)}{f(x)}+O\left(h^2\right)$$
$$\frac 1h\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x-h)} \right)=\frac{ f'(x)}{f(x)}+O\left(h^1\right)$$
$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x-h)} \right)^{\frac 1h}=e^{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}+O\left(h^1\right)$$
$$\frac{\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x-h)}\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}-1}{h}=\frac{e^{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}-1+O\left(h^1\right) } h$$ So, except if $f'(x)=0$, then $???$

**Edit**

Doing the same but continuing Taylor expansions to higher orders, we arrive to
$$\frac{\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(x-h)}\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}-1}{h}=\frac{e^{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}-1 } h+\left(\frac{f'(x)^2}{2 f(x)^2}-\frac{f''(x)}{2 f(x)} \right)e^{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}+O\left(h^2\right)$$ So, there is a limit if $f'(x)=0$ and this limit is $-\frac{f''(x)}{2 f(x)} $.

Comment: Hi, I had reached until here and got stuck.